# Make PostTypeId for WikiPlaceholder posts more granular, or something

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Recently, I wanted to compare the lists of off-topic things on /tour across all sites on the Stack Exchange network. My first instinct was to look to see if those lists (which are proper markdown-enabled posts) were available in the Data Explorer, and indeed they were: [here's the list for Meta.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/338391).

The problem is, these posts are of PostTypeId = 7 "WikiPlaceholder", and they're [not the *only* posts of that type](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/338392). Most sites have up to six of these posts (besides Ask Patents, which apparently has 18), only one of which is the list of off-topic things. Now, since six isn't a large number, I could just pick out the list of off-topic things manually, but this would be a chore if I had to do this for all 150ish SE sites.

So instead, I wrote some code to scrape /tour on all SE sites like a caveman ([see results here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2457/) if you're interested; we have the unique distinction of being the soup-nazi-est site on the network by this metric).

If it were possible to identify different types of WikiPlaceholder posts in the Data Explorer (without manual intervention), I could've just run a query instead and hence gotten those results in a less-cavemannish way (and, plus, this way, the code lives in the Data Explorer, which is more easily accessible than dumping a Python script with non-stdlib dependencies into a gist or whatever). Maybe this entails adding new PostTypeId's, or maybe a new column called WikiPlaceholderTypeId, or something; I dunno.

Comment: For clarity and since it is hilarious: Here comes the [*Soup Nazi*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2lfZg-apSA) so that the young users (?!) know what that is all about. :)